# proof by contradiction: There is no greatest negative real number.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

My textbook wants me to prove the following, using proof by contradiction:

> There is no greatest negative real number

###### Proof:

Assume the negation is true. 
So, there exists a negative real number that is the greatest.

---

Suppose n is negative real number such that $n≥-x$ for every real number $x$. let $n/2=m$.
 Then $m$ is a negative real number since it’s the ratio of negative real number n and $2$. 
 
Also, $m>n$ since n/2=m. Thus, there is a contradiction for n≥-x for every integer x. Therefore the original statement is true.

---

- The first problem is that I am unsure how to formaly write: "n is the greatest negative real number".

> "such that $n≥-x$ for every real number $x$"

- How to provide a reason for $m$ being a negative real number.

> Then $m$ is a negative real number since it’s the ratio of negative real number n and $2$.

Comment: If $\frac n2≥0$ then $n=\frac n2+\frac n2≥0$.

Comment: My problem is how do I write it as an inequality.  For example: If I want to say n is the greatest integer, then I write it as "n≥x for every integer x".                                               
So, i want something similar with n is the greatest negative real number. Should I write "n/2≥x for every negative real number x"?

Comment: Where do "integers" come in?  There is a maximal negative integer, namely $-1$.  I assumed you meant "maximal negative real number" or "maximal negative rational number".

Comment: @lulu this was just an example. what I meant to say is that I want an inequality to represent the greatest negative real numbers, which i now understand to be x≤n<0. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know there is no largest negative number so to prove this by contradiction we assume there is one, call it $n$. Then $n$ has the property that for every $x\lt 0$, $x\le n\lt 0$. That should answer your first question.

For the contradiction, use the fact that for any two numbers $a, b$ with $a\lt b$ $$a\lt b\implies a+a\lt a+b\lt b+b\implies \frac{2a}{2}\lt\frac{a+b}{2}\lt\frac{2b}{2}\implies a\lt\frac{a+b}{2}\lt b$$, i.e. for $a\lt b$, the average of $a$ and $b$ is between $a$ and $b$.

Since, $n\lt 0$, we get that $n\lt\frac{n}{2}\lt 0$ contradicting the fact that $n$ is the largest negative number.

Comment: Your answer for the first question is great. For my second question, your answer explains a lot, but my problem is that it goes way too much into details. Can't I just write "m is a negative real number since it’s the ratio of negative real number n and the integer 2".

Comment: You can say $n\lt 0\implies\frac{n}{2}\lt\frac{0}{2}=0$. Likewise, you can say $n\lt 0\implies n+n\lt 0+n\implies 2n\lt n\implies n\lt\frac{n}{2}$.